# Adding Post Title from custom post type to another custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have different CPT and add post title and Feature Image but i want to add post title from  one CPT to all CPT post title and feature image. Is this possible to add title and feature image from different CPT. im using code.

Example :
CPT1 : Entertainment
CPT2 : Movies
CPT3 : Songs
CPT4 : Videos

CPT1 : Entertainment

Click > Add new Post 
when I editing CPT1, I want to add title and feature image of CPT2, CPT3, CPT4 from CPT1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, Please try below code. add in your functions.php please change post_types according your post type slugs from below code.

```
add_action( 'save_post',  'post_entertainment_save' ) ;


function post_entertainment_save( $post_id ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
    $imageSRC = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail');
    $post_content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);

     // If the post is not "tribe_events", don't create a new post.  
    if ( "entertainment" != $post_type ) 
        return;

    remove_action( 'save_post', 'post_entertainment_save' );

    $movies_post_exists = get_page_by_title( $post_title, $output, "movies" );

    if ( !empty($movies_post_exists) ) {
        // Update post
        $movie_update_post = array(
            'ID'           =>   $movies_post_exists->ID,
            'post_title'   =>   $post_title,
            'post_content' =>   $post_content,
            'post_type'=>'movies', 
        );

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post( $movie_update_post );
        set_post_thumbnail( $movies_post_exists->ID, $post_thumbnail_id );
    }
    else {
        $movie_post = array(
          'post_title'=>$post_title, 
          'post_type'=>'movies', 
          'post_content'=>$post_content,
          'post_status' =>  'publish',
        );
        // Create the new post and retrieve the id of the new post
        $movie_post_id = wp_insert_post ( $movie_post );
        // Set the featured image for the new post to the same image as event post 
        set_post_thumbnail( $movie_post_id, $post_thumbnail_id );
    }   

    $song_post_exists = get_page_by_title( $post_title, $output, "songs" );

    if ( !empty($song_post_exists) ) {
        // Update post
        $songs_update_post = array(
            'ID'           =>   $song_post_exists->ID,
            'post_title'   =>   $post_title,
            'post_content' =>   $post_content,
            'post_type'=>'songs', 
        );

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post( $songs_update_post );
        set_post_thumbnail( $song_post_exists->ID, $post_thumbnail_id );
    }
    else {
        $song_post = array(
          'post_title'=>$post_title, 
          'post_type'=>'songs', 
          'post_content'=>$post_content,
          'post_status' =>  'publish',
        );
        // Create the new post and retrieve the id of the new post
        $song_post_id = wp_insert_post ( $song_post );
        // Set the featured image for the new post to the same image as event post 
        set_post_thumbnail( $song_post_id, $post_thumbnail_id );
    }  


     $video_post_exists = get_page_by_title( $post_title, $output, "videos" );

    if ( !empty($video_post_exists) ) {
        // Update post
        $videos_update_post = array(
            'ID'           =>   $video_post_exists->ID,
            'post_title'   =>   $post_title,
            'post_content' =>   $post_content,
            'post_type'=>'videos', 
        );

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post( $videos_update_post );
        set_post_thumbnail( $video_post_exists->ID, $post_thumbnail_id );
    }
    else {
        $video_post = array(
          'post_title'=>$post_title, 
          'post_type'=>'videos', 
          'post_content'=>$post_content,
          'post_status' =>  'publish',
        );
        // Create the new post and retrieve the id of the new post
        $video_post_id = wp_insert_post ( $video_post );
        // Set the featured image for the new post to the same image as event post 
        set_post_thumbnail( $video_post_id, $post_thumbnail_id );
    }        

    // Now hook the action
    add_action( 'save_post', 'post_entertainment_save' );

  }
```

let me know if this helps to you!